# Mongo user privilege to read and write to any database

Tags: mongodb, authentication

Mongo newb here.  I have a mongo installation with four databases and would like to create a user that can read and write to all the databases.  I tried:

```
use admin;
db.addUser({user: "foo" , pwd: "bar", roles: [  "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]})
```

but when I try to do

```
mongo someotherdb -u foo -p
```

and authenticate with the correct password it gives me an authentication error.

I also tried manually adding the users to the other databases by doing this

```
use someotherdb
db.addUser({user: "foo", roles: ['readWrite'], userSource: "admin"});
```

and still no dice trying to log in via the mongo shell or using the auth command in the target db.

Am I doing something wrong?  How do you go about making a user who can globally read and write to any db?  Do you have to add said user to each db's system.users collection or is that not necessary if they have the "readWriteAnyDatabase" role?

I'm using mongo 2.4 on ubuntu.

Comment: there is a typo in the command use admin. Are you sure the user created? check with : use admin; db.system.users.find(). Once you ensured the user created you can login with mongo localhost:port/admin -u foo -p bar. (unf. you can auth only against admin db with the user created there)

Comment: Woops, yeah, the user was successfully created and can log into the admin db.

Comment: So, is the answer that readWriteAnyDatabase role alone does not allow me to connect to other db's in the mongo instance?

Comment: Does not mean that. It means you have to authenticate but after you will be able to connect. (My understanding is that you authenticate a session which is able to access other dbs in this case only have to auth on the admin db)

Comment: Ever solve this? I'm running into the same problem. I have readWriteAnyDatabase set, can switch databases in the mongo shell but cannot switch in the mongo driver(get a auth failed error), or directly connect to any database other than the admin in the shell.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So, I've finally figured this out.  Note, this fix only works for Mongo 2.4.

In 2.4 you can specify a database to authenticate yourself with in the connection string or on the command line

So to create the initial user

```
use admin
db.createUser({user: "foo" , pwd: "bar", roles: [  "userAdminAnyDatabase","readWriteAnyDatabase" ]})
```

and to authenticate use

```
mongo -u foo --authenticationDatabase admin -p
```

Now you should be able to do whatever you want to any DB

Comment: any way to skip "--authenticationDatabase" option? How use it with php MongoClient class? Robomongo GUI? MongoVUE GUI?

Comment: If you're not using the `authenticationDatabase` option then you'll need to connect into the `admin` database and use `db.auth(...)` to authenticate.

Comment: What if I want to give readWrite permission to a specific database ?

Comment: @LukasLiesis I'm pretty new to this, but it seems like you can use that option implicitly by just passing the authentication database as the first argument. Not sure if you're looking for that or totally eliminating the DB's name. `mongo admin -u 'USERNAME' -p`